# WPF Commands - Bindings don't work, direct calls do. Why?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

---

this question is just for understanding. I'm fine with my IDE telling me about errors that aren't there, as long as the application works.

---

I'm developing a c# WPF application using the MVVM pattern; data and `CommandBindings`.

However, I've noticed that when I use a binding to bind to a `Command`, the command doesn't execute, however, I don't get any errors shown in either the IDE, or debug output.

For example:

```
Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
<!-- Or -->
Command="{Binding cmd:Commands.MyCommand}"
```

However, just writing

```
Command="cmd:Command.MyCommand"
```

works just fine, although the XAML-editor shows me an error, saying that the command cannot be found.

Why is this so?

Comment: Can you show your MyCommand implementation?

Comment: "I'm a web, app, and desktop developer, my job mostly consists in developing software for companies, who require a company-side backend, a server side, and a client-side frontend." Good for you. How do declare MyCommand you are talking about?

Comment: private RelayCommand _myCommand,
/// <summary>
/// Execute a command that does this, this, and this
/// </summary>
public RelayCommand MyCommand {
    get {
        return _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(() => {
            DoSomething();
        }),
        new Func<bool>(() => {
           return true;
        }));
    }
}

Comment: and it's declared in class that represents your viewModel, and then you set this viewmodel as DataContext, right?

Comment: I tried multiple approaches, having the RelayCommand in my ViewModel, and then having it in a static class. I settled on using the static class, because the bindings don't work.

Comment: You cannot bind it, when your relayCommand is static.

Comment: Actually you can if you will write something like this: Command="{Binding Source={x:Static your:staticClass}, Path=MyCommand}"

Comment: No, I know. Hence why I said I tried binding to it, while it was in my ViewModel. After that I changed to using a static class, as that seemed to work for me.

Comment: @VMaleev did not know. Thnx.

Comment: I'm not sure that it matters, but i'd recommend you to change RelayCommand to ICommand in fields declaration (inside getter don't change RelayCommand). Also if you are not able to bind to command inside your viewModel, could you please share a code where it happens? (may be sample in zip in cloud or smthng else) It would be much more easier to recommend something based on your code

Comment: Please, in future, if someone asks for some code, don't paste it into a comment, add it to an [edit].  Comments on SO get deleted regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to a property of type `ICommand`. 
This property will implement a `RelayCommand`  with your function.

The default implementation of the `RelayCommand` is as follows:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    private readonly Action methodToExecute;
    private readonly Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator;
    public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute, Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator)
    {
        this.methodToExecute = methodToExecute;
        this.canExecuteEvaluator = canExecuteEvaluator;
    }
    public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute)
        : this(methodToExecute, null)
    {
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (canExecuteEvaluator == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        bool result = canExecuteEvaluator.Invoke();
        return result;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        methodToExecute.Invoke();
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel you need to implement the property of type `ICommand` with your OnClick-function:

```
public ICommand MyCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            doSomething();
        });
    }
}
```

Now you are able to bind the Button-Command of your view to the ICommand dynamically at runtime:

```
Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
```

Besides, keep in mind that `Command="cmd:Command.MyCommand"` is a static implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is relayCommand that I use:

```
  public sealed class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _action;
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion  Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        if (action != null)
            _action = action;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_execute != null)
            _execute(parameter);
        else
        {
            _action(parameter ?? "Command parameter is null!");
        }
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

What you need is to implement in viewModel command and you will be able to bind it like this:

```
Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
```

**Edit**
As for me, I prefer to use two libraries - interactions and Interactivity. With their help it is easy to bind all events to viewModel. For example:

xaml:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
           <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OnClick"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>                
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and viewModel:

```
public void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //your code
}
```